# Which micro ORM generates one code file per table

Tags: c#, database, micro-orm

I used petapoco but it bumps all in 1 file.

I want to be able to do more rails way - to have 1 generated code file per class.

Thx.

Comment: Does petapoco would (at least in part) as a "custom tool", then? If so, one obstacle is simply: the custom-tool API for multiple files is harder to implement ;p (and it is hard enough for single files!)

Comment: What do you mean by a _micro_ ORM?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [code-first Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) you can structure your code files as you see fit.